# can't retrieve indexPath on prepareforsegue?

Tags: swift

I'm having a problem with retrieving the indexPath on prepareForSegue with the "comments" block. The comments button is inside the cell, and I created a segue from the view controller to the desired vc but every time I click the button, I get an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" on the part where I declare the indexPath.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if (identifier == "webPage1") {
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        if (arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("videoURL") as NSString == "")  {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("comments", sender: nil)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "webPage1") {
        var urlToOpen:String = ""
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        if((arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("videoURL")) != nil) {
            urlToOpen = arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("videoURL") as String

            urlToOpen = urlToOpen.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("http:", withString: "https:", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)


        }

        let sW: webpageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as webpageViewController
        sW.urlPath = urlToOpen
    } else if (segue.identifier == "comments") {
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let sweet:PFObject = arrayByVotes[indexPath.row] as PFObject
        var postId = sweet.objectId

        let selectedFContent: String = arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("content") as String

        let fpvc: FeedPageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FeedPageViewController

        fpvc.selectedFeedFeedContent = selectedFContent
        fpvc.ourpostId = postId
    }

}
```

I then tried wrapping it in an

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
```

but that didn't work either as it wouldn't retrieve the correct indexPath every time.

Essentially the program is supposed to check to see if a cell contains a URL. If it does, it calls the vc with a webview, and if not, then it directly calls the comments page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "webPage1") {

        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
        var urlToOpen = arrayByVotes(selectedRow!) as? String 
        if((urlToOpen != nil) {
            urlToOpen = urlToOpen.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("http:", withString: "https:", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        }

        let sW: webpageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as webpageViewController
        sW.urlPath = urlToOpen
    } else if (segue.identifier == "comments") {
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
        let sweet:PFObject = arrayByVotes(selectedRow!) as PFObject
        var postId = sweet.objectId

        let selectedFContent: String = arrayByVotes(selectedRow!).objectForKey("content") as String

        let fpvc: FeedPageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FeedPageViewController

        fpvc.selectedFeedFeedContent = selectedFContent
        fpvc.ourpostId = postId
    }

}
```

Comment: still getting a fatal error on the part where you declare "sweet"

Comment: let  sweet = arrayByVotes(selectedRow!) as? PFObject